# How to add laravel component in DOM using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, dom-events

I am new on laravel framework.
I have created an **component (lecture-content)** having some files input options, and there is an button onclick which should add one more **(lecture-content) component**. On DOM.

```js
    function addContent()
        {
      let newDoc = "@include('inc.lecture-content')";
      let extendContent = document.getElementById('addNew').innerHtml;
      console.log(extendContent);
      console.log(newDoc);
      extendContent+=newDoc;
      document.getElementById('addNew').innerHtml= extendContent;

    }
```

```html
  <div class="cariculum-heading my-2">
    <h5 class="my-auto py-auto font-weight-normal ">Curriculum </h5>
    <button class="px-2 btn my-auto py-auto add-content-btn" onclick="addContent()" id="add-content">+ content</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="content-section" id="addNew">
    @include('inc.lecture-content')
  </div>
```

but this is not working at this position **let newDoc = "@include('inc.lecture-content')";** it shows syntax error. can anyone help me to resolve it. What I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Use `clone()`

Below jQuery code will fulfill your purpose.

```
function addContent()
        {
          var clone = $('#addNew').clone().css('display','block');
          $('#newEle').append(clone);
        }
```

Add one more div to your blade file.

```
<div id="newEle">
</div>
```

This newly created div will be used to append cloned div.

```js
function addContent()
    {
      var clone = $('#addNew').clone().css('display','block');
      $('#newEle').append(clone);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cariculum-heading my-2">
    <h5 class="my-auto py-auto font-weight-normal ">Curriculum </h5>
    <button class="px-2 btn my-auto py-auto add-content-btn" onclick="addContent()" id="add-content">+ content</button>
  </div>
  <div id="newEle">
  </div>
  <div class="content-section" id="addNew" style="display: none;">
    @include('inc.lecture-content')
  </div>
```